# How does this tricky js assignment work?

Tags: javascript

```
 let at = 1;
 console.log(at + - + + + - ++at);
```

How does this work actually?
I will appreciate any help.

Comment: There is a difference between `++` and `+ +`.

Comment: just out of curiosity what does the console log actually output? This is an interesting question and the output might be valuable to the next person learning.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's not as deep as you probably think it is. :-) It's just this:

```
console.log(at + ++at);
```

The series `- + + + -` is just a bunch of unary `-` and `+`. The `+` don't do anything (in this case, because they're operating on the result of `++at` which is already a number), and the two `-` cancel each other out.

So looking at `at + ++at`: The binary `+` (addition) evaluates its left hand operand, and then its right-hand operand, and then adds them together (when both are numbers). The left-hand operand is `at`, which evaluates to `1`; the right-hand is `++at`, which increments `at` to `2` and takes the new value (`2`) as its result. So, `1 + 2` = `3`.

We can make it even more confusing by removing optional whitespace, leaving only what's required to differentiate between `+` and `++`:

```
console.log(at+-+ + +-++at);
```

...but we wouldn't do that to the people coming after us, would we? :-)

---

If you ever want to see the details of how an expression breaks down, the Esprima folks have a handy page showing the parsing tree of whatever you paste in: http://esprima.org/demo/parse.html

Comment: Thank you a lot for this wonderful resource and your detailed explanation =)